# How can I initialize an array of its length equal to the return of a const int method?

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, size

What I'm trying to accomplish is this:

```
inline const int size() { return 256; }

int main()
{
    int arr[size()];

    return 0;
}
```

But Visual Studio gives me an error when initializing arr[size()]:

> expression must have a constant value

Is there a way to accomplish what I want without using global variables, Macros, std::vector or creating arr[ ] on heap?

Comment: C and C++ are different language. Would you mind choosing one?

Comment: What's the difference between what you're trying to accomplish (if I understood correctly) and declaring `const size = 256;`?

Comment: This essentially boils down to `int arr[256];`, and even better with initialization `int arr[256] = {0};` What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `const` -> `constexpr`?

Comment: I've taken the C tag out since MSVC is not a C compiler. This is a good question now. Have an upvote. You're missing a `constexpr` in there. But `std::vector<int> arr(size());` is better anyway.

Comment: In C++, no (unless your compiler supports non-standard extensions).

Comment: @Bathsheba MSVC can be used as a C compiler. (it is not standard C though: for example it dislikes some standard functions like `scanf()` and `fopen()`) [/Tc, /Tp, /TC, /TP (Specify Source File Type) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/tc-tp-tc-tp-specify-source-file-type?view=msvc-160)

Comment: @MikeCAT: It can but it can't in other words!

Comment: @MikeCAT sorry, I was referring to C++ but thought that in this simple case it would also apply to c

Comment: @a.Li This is just a simple example, in my actual code I need size() to be visible across a variety of methods and I don't want to pass a const int size variable as a parameter for all my methods

Comment: @Bathsheba Thank you very much. Unfortunately I wasn't familiar with constexpr .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drop the `inline` and `const` and add `constexpr` specifier instead, to solve the issue:

```
constexpr int size() { return 256; }
```

now you can use it as array size like:

```
int arr[size()];
```

In C++ (not C) length of arrays must be known at compile time. `const` qualifier only indicates that a value must not change during running time of a program.

By using `constexpr` you will specify that the output of the function is a known constant, even before the program execution.

Comment: @FuqMeOniChan you are welcome. Please also read other answers to understand the reason. Also please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
  and accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like error message is confusing you. The problem is you do not need a `constant value` as message says but [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression):

> Defines an expression that can be evaluated at compile time.

> Such expressions can be used as non-type template arguments, array sizes, and in other contexts that require constant expressions, e.g.

and to achieve that you can add [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) specifier:

> The constexpr specifier declares that it is possible to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time. Such variables and functions can then be used where only compile time constant expressions are allowed (provided that appropriate function arguments are given).

to your function allowing compiler to evaluate it as `constant expression`

```
 constexpr const int size() { return 256; }
```

Note: declaring return type by value as `const` does not really make any difference so you can simply remove that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasn't familiar with    constexpr

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `const` with `constexpr` as others have pointed out, but I should add that your original code compiles fine using the G++ compiler because it supports variable-length arrays, unlike Microsoft's compiler.

Comment: Right, but these are a GCC extension, not standard C++.

Answer (score 1):

From C++20, you can also make `size` an immediate function, i.e. a function that is guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time.

```
consteval int size() { return 256; }
```